# Changing the logic in my jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the script I am working with: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/Jfdbz/19/

Basically it works by geocoding when the submit button is pressed. However, if an option is selected from the auto-suggest link it will geocode the result before the user even presses the button. In this case the script knows it already has the answer, and will not re-geocode the result.

Currently it works by storing the result in this variable:

```
lastQuery
```

Then it does a check to see the following:

```
if (!query || query === lastQuery)
```

However, for the sake of logic, and also to simplify my code which integrates into this code, I was thinking it would be better to do the following:

- Check if the lng lat fields are empty when the submit button is hit, and if so, geocode then submit.
- If the contents of the location field are changed then remove the coordinates from the lng lat fields.

Basically this way it works so if location has been geocoded and unchanged on submission then we have the result and dont need to re-geocode, but any change to the location box before submitting vwill remove the geocoded values, and then the geocoder knows we need to recode the location value when submitted.

I am stuck on how to integrate this logic, and furthermore with my basic knowledge of javascript I'm not sure if this is actually a sensible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlegrimbo/RQvu9/24/) might give you some ideas.

Some main differences are:

#### Turning the google.maps.Geocoder API into a promise based API

[Promises](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) (also see [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)) are often nicer to use than callbacks.

```
// Turn google.maps.Geocoder into promise API
function googleGeocode(query) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(),
        dfd = $.Deferred();

    geocoder.geocode({
        address: query
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            console.log("googleGeocode", "success", query, results);
            dfd.resolve(query, results);
        } else {
            console.log("googleGeocode", "failure", query);
            dfd.reject(query);
        }
    });

    return dfd.promise();
}
```

Then we can use a *maybe* geocode method:

```
// Only geocodes if the query has changed since last time.
function geocode() {
    var geokeyword = $.trim($("#geokeyword").val()),
        loc = $.trim($("#loc").val()),
        // always use geokeyword in preference to loc (if provided)
        query = geokeyword || loc,
        dfd;

    // check for changes
    if (history.query === query) {
        console.log("No changes");
        dfd = $.Deferred();
        // resolve with results already in history
        dfd.resolve(history.query, history.results);
        return dfd.promise();
    }

    return googleGeocode(query);
}
```

#### Use of a history object

(a single object is shown here, but your history could be an array or map of all previous geocode results)

```
var history = {
    lat: null,
    long: null,
    query: null,
    results: null
},
```

which is checked when a geocode is requested (see above), and updated when a successful geocode has been performed (see below - the success callback is the first callback passed to `then()`, and the error callback is the second):

```
function processLocation(history, submit) {
    // only passing submit==false will prevent auto-submission
    submit = (false !== submit);

    geocode().then(function (query, results) {
        var form = $("#geocode_form"),
            lat = form.find("#lat"),
            long = form.find("#lng"),
            location = results[0].geometry.location;

        console.log("processLocation", "success", query, results);

        lat.val(location.lat());
        long.val(location.lng());

        history.query = query;
        history.results = results;
        history.lat = lat.val();
        history.long = long.val();

        if (submit) {
            console.log("Submitting", lat.val(), long.val());
            form.submit();
        }
    }, function (query) {
        console.log("processLocation", "failure", query);
    });
}
```